# How do check if an input of string type is present in a list, using conditions?

Tags: python, string, list, input, conditional-statements

```
pizzas = ['oriental', 'salami', 'indian', '4cheese', 'beef'] 

for questions in pizzas:
    questions = input("Do u like ")
    if questions in pizzas:
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

Here want to ask the user to input a type of pizza. And if that pizza type that the user has entered is in the "pizzas" list, I want the console to output yes. So I made this program but it always outputs 'No' in this case. Sorry if I am not explaining properly. Thanks.

Comment: In `pizzas == questions` you're comparing a list and a string for _equality_, and a string can never be _equal_ to a list, so you'll always be getting `No` as the answer. You're looking for the `in` operator

Comment: @ForceBru I tried that but it didn't work...

Comment: @Lasersapien, what did you try and how exactly did it not work?

Comment: @ForceBru I've changed "if questions == pizzas" to "if questions in pizzas" like u said and it always outputs no

Comment: The loop is un-needed. Just delete the `for questions...` line.

Comment: @Lasersapien, [works fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYL8m.png)

Comment: @ForceBru And also it works when I input only 1 letter (ex : pizzas = 'y', 'oriental'...) . So here if I enter y for the input it outputs 'yes'.

Comment: @Lasersapien, great? This is what this code is supposed to do

Comment: @ForceBru What!? How does it work for u. Did u try to enter anything else than what is in the list? No, I want the program to say 'yes' if I enter a string wich is in the list and 'no' if not. But in my case I can only enter a letter and not a string. And if I delete the "if questions..." line I could only input once.

Comment: @Lasersapien, you surely can enter more than one character - see my screenshot. And it will indeed output `No` if you enter something that's not in the list, like `ForceBru`

Comment: @ForceBru oh I see, it only works if I input the words in the correct order. But try to once input a value not present in the list and then a value in the list. U will see that it will output no. And thanks u helped me a lot till now

Comment: @Lasersapien, you can input the words in whatever order you like. If you input something that's not present in the list _and then hit Enter_, `No` will be printed. If you then input, say, `salami`, the output will be `Yes`, as expected

Comment: @ForceBru Are u sure? Did u try it with ur one?

Comment: @Lasersapien, [yes, I am](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1GDe.jpg)

Comment: @ForceBru wwuahh what. Amazing. Sadly it doesn't work for me. I use sublime text 3 as editor and cmd for output. And is the program of this output the same as the one u showed me before?

Comment: @Lasersapien, then close Sublime Text and type this code straight into the Python interpreter. Looks like you're either not saving the file or running the wrong file altogether.

Comment: @ForceBru I always save the file after modifications. Yeah thanks I'm gonna try it.

Comment: @ForceBru Ohhh hey I'm stupid. I was accidently using a space after typing a word and that's why it gave me this problem. Because u know that programming languages see spaces as input values. Arghhghg I need to be more careful on stupid errors like this. I'm a beginner in coding so I'm learning. Thanks for all the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop in this case, just use in operator:

```
pizzas = ['oriental', 'salami', 'indian', '4cheese', 'beef'] 
questions = raw_input("Do u like ")
if questions in pizzas:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

Comment: it says 'raw_input' isn't defined, doesn't work in python 3

Comment: @Lasersapien, that's because this answer is written for Python 2. Change `raw_input` to `input` to make it work in Python 3

Comment: @ForceBru yeah ik but it won't loop. So i need the loop + input()

Comment: @Lasersapien, I don't really understand why you're looping here. `for questions in pizzas:` will loop over each pizza, but after `questions = input(...)` the name `questions` now refers to user input, not the pizza, so the loop is now essentially the same as `for _ in range(len(pizzas)):`, which will repeat the loop's body `len(pizzas)` times... for no apparent reason

Comment: @ForceBru yeah ik i could also do "for questions in range(1, 100)" or "while(1) " to loop

Answer (score 0):

it's because you're using "=" instead of "=="
you don't have to use forloop

if questions in pizza:
    print("yes*)
else:
    print("no")

sorry code not formatted properly im using a phone